# Add text/cell bold and underlined using itextsharp

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

I want to add a text in a cell using itextsharp which will be bold and underlined.
I am creating the font like this:

```
Dim mssanserif As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "MICROSS.TTF")
Dim mssanserifBaseFont As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(mssanserif, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)
Dim Font7 As Font = New Font(mssanserifBaseFont, 7, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL)
Dim Font7_ As Font = New Font(mssanserifBaseFont, 7, iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE)
Dim FontBold8 As Font = New Font(mssanserifBaseFont, 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)
Dim Font7bold_ As Font = New Font(mssanserifBaseFont, 7, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD And iTextSharp.text.Font.UNDERLINE)
```

but when i use the Font7bold_

```
iphrase = New Phrase()
text = "bla bla bla"
iphrase.Add(New Chunk(text, Font7bold_))
c = New PdfPCell(iphrase)
Table1.AddCell(c)
```

i get a bold text but with strikethrough style and not underlined.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Applying multiple font styles is done with an OR, not an AND. Try that?

Comment: Thanks, it was so simple. I was so possitive it was AND :)